# Kafka Streams KTable-KTable non key join performance on skewed tables

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

We have two table Merchant and Product, which have one-to-many relationship. Merchant is very skewed so one merchant have many products. We can join these two KTable by merchantId using non-key join.

When Merchant is updated, lots of events arrives on `KTABLE-FK-JOIN-SUBSCRIPTION-RESPONSE` and this is expected behavior. But the problem is consuming `KTABLE-FK-JOIN-SUBSCRIPTION-RESPONSE` events is very slow and have some kind of upper bound. More specifically, the speed of emitting responses is proportional to the merchants changes, while the speed of materializing non-key join results into the changelog is limited.

Since valueJoiner only performs very lightweight object allocation work, I can't understand why consuming `KTABLE-FK-JOIN-SUBSCRIPTION-RESPONSE` is slow and limited to some bound. How can we increase throughput in the current situation?

Comment: I’m struggling with the same issue in a service with three topics consumed as KTables and joined via foreign key. Did you find any solution or at least improvement?

Answer (score 0):

My solution was the strict separation of deployment and operation of the software, so that different runtime properties could be set among others for Kafka.
The most important setting however was `acks: 1` instead of the default `acks: all` during deployment resulting in an improvement of **an order of magnitude**. Although only three brokers are part of the cluster it was a game-changer; I couldn't even come near with any other tuning attempts.
Thus, the deployments now only take 10 minutes instead of several hours.