# Insane throughput slowdown kafka streams using join (kstream & ktable) using jmh and TopologyTestDriver

Tags: join, apache-kafka-streams, jmh, ktable

Am trying to measure relative throughput of my kafka streams app using `jmh` and `TopologyTestDriver`.  This is on an M1 Mac but all numbers are relative anyway so eh.
Anyway when piping directly from my input topic to my output topic:

```
public class EventTopologyMulti {
  public static StreamsBuilder topology() {
    StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();

    // Main topic
    KStream<String, Event> mainEvents = builder.<String, Event>stream("event_ingestion");

    mainEvents.to("enriched_events");
    return builder;
  }
}
```

& then running `jmh` I get:

```
TopologyBenchMulti.benchmarkTopology  thrpt    4  34548.895 ± 6484.374  ops/s
```

Spectacular - love it - all good.

BUT as soon as I join with one table it all goes horribly wrong:

```
public class EventTopologyMulti {
  public static StreamsBuilder topology() {
    StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();

    // Main topic
    KStream<String, Event> mainEvents = builder.<String, Event>stream("event_ingestion");
     
    // Topic to table-ize & join
    KStream<String, Event> identifyStream = builder.<String, Event>stream("indentify");

    // Create the table
    KTable<String, Event> identifyTable = identifyStream.toTable();

    // Create the ValueJoiner
    final EventWithIdentify identifyJoiner = new EventWithIdentify();

    // Do the join & send to final topic
    mainStream.leftJoin(identifyTable, identifyJoiner).to("enriched_events");

    return builder;
  }
}
```

And I run `jmh` again WOW:

```
TopologyBenchMulti.benchmarkTopology  thrpt    4  22.934 ± 2.394  ops/s
```

!!! Went from **35k** -> **23** ops/s????

YES both topics use the same `key` value for each record. Yes the topics are co-partitioned (although running via `TopologyTestDriver` that doesn't matter). Both topics ingest the same shape value are keyed with the same value so it should be super easy/straightforward/not require any extra processing.

Here is my value joiner - that does nothing:

```
public class EventWithIdentify implements ValueJoiner<Event, Event, Event> {
  public Event apply(Event event, Event identifyEvent) {
    return event;
  }
}
```

Note I get this kind of massive slowdown whether it's `join` or `leftJoin`.
Also get the same slowdown if I send all `Events` to the same topic & then branch them & then to the `KTable` & then the `leftJoin` (using `.split().branch(...)`).

Funnily enough I get an even larger slowdown if I use `Materialized('identify-table')` when converting the `KStream` to a `KTable` (`.to(Materialized.as('identify-table'))`) !!

What the heck is going on?  Sure I'd expect some slowdown but not this much!!!

For completeness here is the `jmh` test code:

```
public class TopologyBenchMulti {

  private static final String SCHEMA_REGISTRY_SCOPE = TopologyBenchMulti.class.getName();
  private static final String MOCK_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL = "mock://" + SCHEMA_REGISTRY_SCOPE;
  private static TopologyTestDriver testDriver;

  @State(org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.Scope.Thread)
  public static class MyState {
    public TestInputTopic<String, Event> mainEventsTopic;
    public TestInputTopic<String, Event> identifyTopic;
    public Event regStartedEvent;

    @Setup(Level.Trial)
    public void setupState() {
      Properties props = new Props().props;
      props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "test");
      props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "dummy:1234");
      props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
      props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, SpecificAvroSerde.class);
      props.put("schema.registry.url", MOCK_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL);

      // build the topology
      Topology topology = EventTopologyMulti.topology().build();

      // create a test driver. we will use this to pipe data to our topology
      testDriver = new TopologyTestDriver(topology, props);

      // create the avro value serde
      Serde<Event> avroEventSerde = new SpecificAvroSerde<>();
      Map<String, String> config = Map.of("schema.registry.url", MOCK_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL);
      avroEventSerde.configure(config, false);

      // create the test topics
      mainEventsTopic =
          testDriver.createInputTopic(
              "event_ingestion", Serdes.String().serializer(), avroEventSerde.serializer());

      identifyTopic =
        testDriver.createInputTopic(
          "identify_event", Serdes.String().serializer(), avroEventSerde.serializer());

      Event identifyEvent =
          Event.newBuilder()
            .setId("foofie")
            .setTimestamp(Instant.now())
            .setEventName(EventName.Identify)
            .setEvent(Identify.newBuilder().setUserId("userid-99").build())
            .build();
      identifyTopic.pipeInput("anonymous id", identifyEvent);

      regStartedEvent =
        Event.newBuilder()
          .setId("goofie")
          .setTimestamp(Instant.now())
          .setEventName(EventName.RegistrationStarted)
          .setEvent(
              RegistrationStarted.newBuilder()
             .setAuthenticationMethod(RegistrationMethod.email)
                  .build())
          .build();
    }

    @TearDown(Level.Trial)
    public void tearDown() {
      testDriver.close();
    }
  }

  @Benchmark
  @BenchmarkMode(Mode.Throughput)
  @OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.SECONDS)
  public void benchmarkTopology(MyState state) {
    state.mainEventsTopic.pipeInput("anonymous id", state.regStartedEvent);
  }
}
```

And finally in my `build.gradle`:

```
jmh {
  iterations = 4
  benchmarkMode = ['thrpt']
  threads = 1
  fork = 1
  timeOnIteration = '3s'
  resultFormat = 'TEXT'
  profilers = []
  warmupIterations = 3
  warmup = '1s'
}
```

It's can't actually be this slow by just adding one `join` on 1 table??  Is it `TopologyTestDriver` is it me???

Losing hair over this thanks for any input!!!!

Comment: Please put the complete code of your benchmark

Comment: updated to add all jmh code thanks!

Comment: Well, you benchmark seems to be correct, so I'd suggest to use JMH's GCProfiler and JavaFlightRecorderProfiler to find out what is slowing down your application.

Comment: Could you try to use a in-memory store (`Stores.inMemoryKeyValueStore("name");`)? I remember seeing some performance problems with RocksDB on mac

Comment: I’m struggling with the same issue in a service with three topics consumed as KTables and joined via foreign key. Did you find any solution or at least improvement? A bit more details can be found in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74876325/kafka-streams-ktable-ktable-non-key-join-performance-on-skewed-tables

Comment: In your case using Kafka Streams’ cogrouping feature might be a relief since your topics use the same key and are co-partitioned.